# Display mapped labels instead of codes in Pandas pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, pivot-table, categorical-data

Putting together some pivot tables in Pandas from a dataset of predominantly categorical variables, that are entirely represented in numerical codes with an accompanying codebook/dictionary.

I want the category labels to display instead of the numerical code. I could not find an answer for this elsewhere or in the Pandas documentation.

e.g...

```
gender_dict = {1: "Male", 2: "Female"}
df['gender'].map(gender_dict)

pd.pivot_table(df, values=['location'], index=['gender'], aggfunc=len)
```

... and rather than the gender in the table showing 1 & 2, I want it to show the labels "Male" & "Female"

Thanks
B

Comment: `df['gender'] = df['gender'].map(gender_dict)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do it after creating the pivot table:

```
df_out = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['location'], index=['gender'], aggfunc=len)
df_out.index = df_out.index.to_series().map(gender_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks both for your answers. Much appreciated.